# how to add xml tag as body in the attachment?

Tags: apex, attachment, xml

I am trying to form dynamic package.xml in my code.So i want a sample template as attachment under a object.I tried as below.It's not working .

Code:-

```
String str='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <contentToreplace></contentToreplace>
    <version>37.0</version>
</Package>';

Attachment att = new Attachment();                    

att.Description = 'ANT Component';

att.Body = Blob.valueOf();
att.ParentId = 'a4D4B0000001Vxu';
insert att;
```

I will replace this  by the values i formed

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You missed to pass `str` as parameter of Blob.valueOf method `att.Body = Blob.valueOf(str);` and Name of attchment

The following code works:

```
String str='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
    +'<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">'
        +'<contentToreplace></contentToreplace>'
        +'<version>37.0</version>'
    +'</Package>';

Attachment att = new Attachment();                    

att.Description = 'ANT Component';
att.Name = 'Ant';
att.Body = Blob.valueOf(str);
att.ParentId = '00Q0v0000019RaD'; // related record id
insert att;
```